# Finding prime factors in C

Tags: c, primes

I am trying to generate all the prime factors of a number `n`. When I give it the number `126` it gives me 2, 3 and 7 but when I give it say `8` it gives me 2, 4 and 8.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
int findPrime(unsigned long n)
{
  int testDivisor, i;
  i = 0;
  testDivisor = 2;
  while (testDivisor < n + 1)
  {
    if ((testDivisor * testDivisor) > n)
    {
    //If the test divisor squared is greater than the current n, then 
    //the current n is either 1 or prime. Save it if prime and return
    }
    if (((n % testDivisor) == 0))
    {
      prime[i] = testDivisor;
      if (DEBUG == 1) printf("prime[%d] = %d\n", i, prime[i]);
      i++;
      n = n / testDivisor;
    }
    testDivisor++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an if statement with an empty block?

Comment: my teacher gave that as part of his suggested algorithm

Comment: As long as you are not dealing with big numbers, Robert Martin's TDD Kata for finding prime factors is the most elegant solution out there. Give it a shot here at [CloudCoder](https://cloudcoder.org/demo/#exercise?c=3,p=48)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing `testDivisor` even when you were able to divide `n` by it. Only increase it when it is not divisible anymore. This will result in `2,2,2`, so you have to modify it a bit further so you do not store duplicates, but since this is a homework assignment I think you should figure that one out yourself :)

Comment: ie You have to <OBFUSCATED SINCE IT'S HOMEWORK>

Comment: @quasiverse: Yes! deleted mine as well ^^

Comment: Any hints on how not to store duplicates?

Comment: No. This should be fairly simple, and you should really be able to figure this one out for yourself as a homework assignment, judging by the assignment, and my experience as a teacher that is definitely not too much to ask.

Comment: This is part of a complicated encryption program that is 500 lines long :/

Answer (score 2):

Is this based on an algorithm your professor told you to implement or is it your own heuristic? In case it helps, some known algorithms for prime factorization are the Quadratic Sieve and the General Number Field Sieve.

Comment: This is called _Direct Search Factorization_ and is by far the easiest to implement. See: [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectSearchFactorization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the quadratic sieve algorithm, which factors 170-bit integers in second and 220-bit integers in minute. There is a pure C implementation here that does not require GMP or an external library : https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-Quadratic-Sieve, it's able to provide you a list of the prime factors of N. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you aren't checking if any divisors you find are prime. As long as `n % testDivisor == 0` you are counting `testDivisor` as a prime factor. Also, you are only dividing through by `testDivisor` once. You could fix this a number of ways, one of which would be to replace the statement `if (((n % testDivisor) == 0))` with `while (((n % testDivisor) == 0))`.

Fixing this by adding the while loop also ensures that you won't get composite numbers as divisors, as if they still divide `n`, a smaller prime factor must have also divided `n` and the while loop for that prime factor wouldn't have left early.

Comment: **[edit] You've edited your post, now this comment is obsolete :)** -- Sorry, you are wrong. This IS actually happening, although a bit obfuscated. If you keep dividing by a number (starting from 2) until it is not divisible anymore, you can safely increase the divisor. It cannot be divided any further by any multiple 2. After the next round it cannot be divided by any multiple of 3, etc... This way you will only find divisors which are in itself not divisible, thus prime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to find the Prime Factor:

```
long GetPrimeFactors(long num, long *arrResult)
{
    long count = 0;
    long arr[MAX_SIZE];

    long i = 0;

    long idx = 0;

    for(i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
      if(IsPrimeNumber(i) == true)
          arr[count++] = i;
    }

    while(1)
    {
      if(IsPrimeNumber(num) == true)
      {
          arrResult[idx++] = num;
          break;
      }
      for(i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
          if( (num % arr[i]) == 0)
          {
            arrResult[idx++] = arr[i];
            num = num / arr[i];
            break;
          }
      }
    }
    return idx;
}
```

Reference: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/Prime_Factor.html